# Chrome Extension: Programmatically setting browser action icon causes the icon to pixelate

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to change the browser action icon in background.js using the following code

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "img/logo-off.png", tabId:tab.id});
```

However, this is causing the icon to be pixelated really bad (flappy bird style).

Has anyone had the same problem? How should I solve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just finally got my hands on Chrome 38 on a high-DPI Windows screen, and it shows the same behavior.

For high-DPI screens, you need to provide higher-resolution icons, and update the icon [providing alternatives](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon):

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path: {
    19: "img/logo-off.png",
    38: "img/logo-off-hidpi.png"
  },
  tabId: tab.id
});
```

Chrome will select appropriate image based on screen DPI. It currently supports only 19x19 and 38x38 scales.

**Edit (June 2016):**

Chrome appears to be moving towards Material Design for its toolbar, and that [changes browser icon requirements to 16x16](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546206) (32x32 for HiDPI). It's advised to provide those as well to be ready for the switch (which [already happened in Linux](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=612765), intentionally or not).

Comment: If you are using manifest 3, you will need `chrome.action.setIcon`